# Is there a family equivalent to "congener"?

Tags: taxonomy, nomenclature

Is there an equivalent word to "congener" but for species in the same family (family in the sense of the taxonomic rank)?

"confamer"? "confamiler"???

I know I can just say "species X and other taxa in the same family" but I thought a nice one-worder would be better if anybody uses such a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confamilial is the term for same family, it has [even been used in print](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1691288/).

> Congenerics were twice as likely to fight as conspecifics, and **confamilial** competitors were three times as likely to fight as conspecifics.

Comment: I just found "confamilial" as well in a different paper.